# "Emulating" HID Gamepad

Tags: hid, emulation, gamepad

Since we are still [struggling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551322/sending-and-receiving-bluetoth-packets) with sending and receiving bluetooth data, we want to try a different way, ignoring bluetooth for now.
Is it possible to write a software, which Windows or Linux is recognizing as a Hardware Gamepad for simulating (so we only need to change the input of that tool to bluetooth input later)?
And if it is possible, what do I need to know for achieving that? Thank you!

(We are using C/C++)